# Difference between import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native'; and import AppRegistry from 'react-native';

Tags: javascript, react-native, vue.js, ecmascript-6

sometimes we load something in es6 like:

```
import FlatList from 'react-native';
```

but sometimes we covered this imported object with curly brackets like

```
import {'FlatList'} from 'react-native';
```

please tell me when should use this brackets or not.

Comment: Pretty sure this will be a duplicate question, but you use curly braces when it is not the default export and no curly braces when it is the default export

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the difference between a **named** export and a **default** export. [Ref](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reactjs-importing-exporting/)

If the module exports a module as a default (ex: `export default FlatList;`), it can be accessed by `import FlatList from "react-native"`.

If it's a named export (ex: `export const FlatList;`), it will have to be imported as `import {FlatList} from "react-native"`.

It's entirely up to the module authors to export it as they see fit. You should consult the documentation to know how to import it for sure.